# python AttributeError opencv

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror

i am new to opencv and am trying to simply display an image, however with every cv2 function I get the same error, (AttributeError)

I have already installed pip install opencv-contrib-python witch was suggested to fix this problem but changed nothing,

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread ("C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\desktop backround pics\\560736.jpg", 1)
print(img)
cv2.imshow("560736",img)
cv2.WaitKey(2000)
cv2.DestroyAllWindows()
```

full error is.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Astroid/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 6, in 
    cv2.WaitKey(20000)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'WaitKey'

Answer (score 0):

Use lowercase for the method: [[docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7)]

```
retval = cv.waitKey([, delay])
```

Comment: thx, that worked for waitkey however i sayed that the same AttributeError was happening to all the cv2 functions, after i implemented your line of code it desplaye the image however the program ended in

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Astroid/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.DestroyAllWindows()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'DestroyAllWindows'

and when i implemented this line in 

reasized = cv2.reasize(img, (800,600))

the same happend

Comment: The naming convention across `cv2` is lowercase for first letter then camel case so it should be `destroyAllWindows()`